# What are the English font types already trained for tesseract 3.02

Tags: tesseract

I want to know what are the different font types of English language already trained for tesseract 3.02.
1. Is there a way to find this ?
2. Is this information documented any where ?

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the fonts can be found in `eng.traineddata` file itself. Unpack it and look at the `.tr` files or inside `.inttemp` file.

References:

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=759
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tesseract-ocr/QQsenFJkeNg
http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r757/trunk/tessdata/eng.cube.size